# Extracting Numbers with Commas from String

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, extract

I want to extract a number of squared meters from a house description column. For example, I used:

```
df['description'].str.extract('(\d\,\d{1,3}\s?[sS])', expand=True)
```

to extract 3000 from a string that looks like "The house is 3,000 square meters".

What if I wanted to extract 800 square meters? So a condition that does not involve the comma. How would I add that to the condition. Sorry I looked around and still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: how about just `[,\d]+`?

Comment: Sorry but how would I combine that into the parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I am using `str.findall`

```
s=pd.Series(['llll llll llll 100,000.00 lll lll ll ','xyz 800 bgm bhd','80','1,000.00 and 10'])
s.str.findall(r'(?:[,\d]+.?\d*)')
0      [100,000.00]
1             [800]
2              [80]
3    [1,000.00, 10]
dtype: object
```